# How to select multiple files and copy them in Far Manager

Tags: far-manager

Is there a way I can select a file and navigate to another one and select it again?

say if I press  then the current file would be selected, then I can navigate to another file then press  again, which also selects the second file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the files reside in the same folder, you can select mutiple files by using the <kbd>INS</kbd> key. If the files reside in different folders, you can use the temporary panel to aggregate them - you do that by copying them over to the temporary panel with <kbd>F5</kbd>. The temporary panel should be included in your FAR manager, just press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and look in the list. Note that if you delete a file in the temporary panel by using <kbd>F8</kbd>, the actual file will be deleted, not the reference. Use <kbd>F7</kbd> to remove the references from temporary panel.